# Xcode 10.2.1 is not supporting ios 12.3.1 for deployment/testing purpose?

Tags: ios, xcode

when I'm trying to deploy/test my app in a real device, I'm facing the issue. The error is in the image attached.

This is the error :

[image]

My Xcode version is 10.2.1

My IOS software version is 12.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Your device iOS version maybe higher than what your current xCode version can handle, thus when you try to test it has an error.

1. Check that you are running the latest version of xCode.
2. If iOS software version 12.3.1 is a beta version, you'll need to download and use the Beta version of xCode.

Comment: But there’s currently no beta software available for download. I am running the latest version of Xcode 10.2.1(10E1001). I think the version of Xcode is release version.